# Combine two foreach Arrays into one table row

Tags: array, php

right now I have two foreach arrays - one outputs the artist, the other a track title

I would like to combine both so there is a row for each artist and corresponding track

for example:

Row 1 - Artist 1  Track 1 
Row 2 - Artist 2  Track 2

```
<?php // Get duplicate fields
$duplicate_field = get_post_custom_values('Artist', $post->ID);
foreach ( $duplicate_field as $key => $value ) {
echo $value . '<br />'; 
}
?>

<?php // Get duplicate fields
$duplicate_field = get_post_custom_values('Track', $post->ID);
foreach ( $duplicate_field as $key => $value ) {
echo $value . '<br />'; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the artist names and track names are in matching order and the same in number then:

```
<?php
$artists = get_post_custom_values('Artist', $post->ID);
$tracks = get_post_custom_values('Track', $post->ID);
$i=0;
foreach ( $artists as $key => $value ) {
    $class = ( $i % 2 ) ? 'alternative' : ''; // modulus operator
    echo '<li class="' . $class . '">';
    echo $value . ' - '; 
    echo tracks[ $i ] . '</li>';
    $i++;
}
?>
```

otherwise if there is some other way they are matched up you need to figure that out in the loop.

Comment: worked perfectly! Is there a way to have every other <tr> to have a inline style such as <tr style="background-color: #ccc;">

Comment: I've edited the answer to add the alternative row class. (don't forget to mark the answer as correct and vote it up. I'm a point whore today ;)

Comment: Thanks Again! Everything displays but the sort order is incorrect. I opened a separate thread with the issue here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38793/multiple-custom-fields-sort-order